# Stored procedure not working while calling in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hope everyone is doing good.

I have started working on snowflake. I am trying to create a stored and procedure and calling this SP. Stored procedure is created without any issue. While calling it is saying that unexpected invalid token.

```
JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught Syntax issue: Invalid or unexpected token in USP_USERS at INSERT INTO stg.users_Temp position 0
```

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ods.usp_Users()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var sql_command = 
"INSERT INTO stg.users_Temp
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(id)) AS Id
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(name)) AS Name
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(divisionId)) AS DivisionId
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(divisionName)) AS DivisionName
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(department)) AS Department
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(email)) AS Email
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(state)) AS State
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(title)) AS Title
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) AS Username
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(managerId)) AS ManagerId
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(employeeId)) AS employeeId
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(employeeType)) AS employeeType
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(officialName)) AS officialName
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(dateHire)) AS dateHire
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(LocationId)) AS LocationId
FROM stg.users;

    MERGE INTO 
        ods.Users  AS t 
    USING 
        stg.users_Temp s
    ON 
        (
            s.Id =  t.Id 
        )
    WHEN 
        MATCHED 
    THEN 
        UPDATE 
    SET  
         t.Name                 =   s.Name
        ,t.DivisionId               =   s.DivisionId
        ,t.DivisionName         =   s.DivisionName
        ,t.Department               =   s.Department
        ,t.Email                    =   s.Email
        ,t.State                    =   s.State
        ,t.Title                    =   s.Title
        ,t.Username             =   s.Username
        ,t.LocationId             =   s.LocationId
        ,t.ManagerId                =   s.ManagerId
        ,t.employeeId               =   s.employeeId
        ,t.employeeType         =   s.employeeType
        ,t.officialName         =   s.officialName
        ,t.dateHire             =   s.dateHire
        ,t.EtlLastUpdatedDate       =   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() :: TIMESTAMP
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT 
        (
             id
            ,Name
            ,DivisionId
            ,DivisionName
            ,Department
            ,Email
            ,State
            ,Title
            ,Username
            ,LocationId
            ,ManagerId
            ,employeeId     
            ,employeeType   
            ,officialName   
            ,dateHire   
            ,CurrentRecord
            ,EtlCreatedDate
        )
    VALUES 
        (
             s.id
            ,s.Name
            ,s.DivisionId
            ,s.DivisionName
            ,s.Department
            ,s.Email
            ,s.State
            ,s.Title
            ,s.Username
            ,s.LocationId
            ,s.ManagerId
            ,s.employeeId       
            ,s.employeeType 
            ,s.officialName 
            ,s.dateHire
            ,'1'
            ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() :: TIMESTAMP
        );"
 try { 
    snowflake.execute (
      {sqlText: sql_command}
      );
    return "Succeeded.";  // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
  catch (err) {
    return "Failed: " + err;  // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
TRUNCATE TABLE stg.users_Temp;
$$
;


//call ods.usp_Users();
```

While call SP it is throwing an error

Could someone help me on this issue.

Regards,
Khatija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the backtick (`) character to define multi-line strings:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ods.usp_Users()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var sql_command = 
`BEGIN
  INSERT INTO stg.users_Temp
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(id)) AS Id
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(name)) AS Name
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(divisionId)) AS DivisionId
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(divisionName)) AS DivisionName
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(department)) AS Department
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(email)) AS Email
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(state)) AS State
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(title)) AS Title
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) AS Username
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(managerId)) AS ManagerId
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(employeeId)) AS employeeId
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(employeeType)) AS employeeType
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(officialName)) AS officialName
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(dateHire)) AS dateHire
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(LocationId)) AS LocationId
FROM stg.users;

    MERGE INTO 
        ods.Users  AS t 
    USING 
        stg.users_Temp s
    ON 
        (
            s.Id =  t.Id 
        )
    WHEN 
        MATCHED 
    THEN 
        UPDATE 
    SET  
         t.Name                 =   s.Name
        ,t.DivisionId               =   s.DivisionId
        ,t.DivisionName         =   s.DivisionName
        ,t.Department               =   s.Department
        ,t.Email                    =   s.Email
        ,t.State                    =   s.State
        ,t.Title                    =   s.Title
        ,t.Username             =   s.Username
        ,t.LocationId             =   s.LocationId
        ,t.ManagerId                =   s.ManagerId
        ,t.employeeId               =   s.employeeId
        ,t.employeeType         =   s.employeeType
        ,t.officialName         =   s.officialName
        ,t.dateHire             =   s.dateHire
        ,t.EtlLastUpdatedDate       =   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() :: TIMESTAMP
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT 
        (
             id
            ,Name
            ,DivisionId
            ,DivisionName
            ,Department
            ,Email
            ,State
            ,Title
            ,Username
            ,LocationId
            ,ManagerId
            ,employeeId     
            ,employeeType   
            ,officialName   
            ,dateHire   
            ,CurrentRecord
            ,EtlCreatedDate
        )
    VALUES 
        (
             s.id
            ,s.Name
            ,s.DivisionId
            ,s.DivisionName
            ,s.Department
            ,s.Email
            ,s.State
            ,s.Title
            ,s.Username
            ,s.LocationId
            ,s.ManagerId
            ,s.employeeId       
            ,s.employeeType 
            ,s.officialName 
            ,s.dateHire
            ,'1'
            ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() :: TIMESTAMP
        );
END`
 try { 
    snowflake.execute (
      {sqlText: sql_command}
      );
    return "Succeeded.";  // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
  catch (err) {
    return "Failed: " + err;  // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
// TRUNCATE TABLE stg.users_Temp;
$$
;
```

PS: You can't user trancate as you tried to do, you should also call it using snowflake.execute. And when you run this proc, it would fail with "Failed: Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.". To overcome this issue, you can break up queries, and execute them separately or surround them in a BEGIN/END block.

Comment: Thanks Gokhan. I am a new bee to snowflake. can you give more details on need to break up queries, and execute them separately.  On what basis we can break into multiple statements.

Comment: Never mind about breaking them, you can also put them in BEGIN and END; Updating my answer.

Comment: Hi Gokhan, I have ran the SP. Now it is working. You are awesome. If I want to truncate to my stg.Users_temp table before merge. How can we do. Sorry for asking more questions

Comment: You mean before INSERT right? Because you insert and then you MERGE using the contents of the table. In this case, you should be able to add TRUNCATE before INSERT command (in the same BEGIN/END block)